# Use Grab to Download Ivy Dependency Jar when Artifact name is not the same as Module name

Tags: jenkins, groovy, dependency-management, ivy, groovy-grape

Within a Jenkins groovy script I'm trying to download a dependency using the following:

```
@Grab(group='myorg', module='SuiteCreator', version='1.16.1', conf='jar', transitive=false)
import myorg.myorgAPI
```

I have a */home/jenkins/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml* file with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-settings>
    <settings defaultResolver="downloadGrapes"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="downloadGrapes">
            <sftp user="admin" userPassword="pw" host="ivy.myorg.com" name="myrepository" checkmodified="true">
                <ivy pattern="/data/ivy/repo/[organisation]/[module]/[branch]/[revision]/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
                <artifact pattern="/data/ivy/repo/[organisation]/[module]/[branch]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
            </sftp>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivy-settings>
```

The *ivy-1.16.1.xml* of the Module I've trying to grab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="1.0">
    <info organisation="myorg" module="SuiteCreator" branch="master" revision="1.16.1" status="release" publication="20190417105814"/>
    <configurations>
        <conf name="jar" description="Distribution jar"/>
    </configurations>

    <publications>
        <artifact name="myorg-suitecreator" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="jar"/>
    </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

So I'm just trying to grab the artifact: **myorg-suitecreator-1.16.1.jar**.

When I run my groovy script in Jenkins I get the following error:

> 2019.07.09 18:06:15 org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed:
>   2019.07.09 18:06:15 General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed:
>   myorg#SuiteCreator#master;1.16.1!SuiteCreator.jar]
>   2019.07.09 18:06:15 
>   2019.07.09 18:06:15 java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: myorg#SuiteCreator#master;1.16.1!SuiteCreator.jar]
>   2019.07.09 18:06:15   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

From the error it seems Grape is assuming the Ivy Artifact Name is the same as the Module name. The ivy-1.16.1.xml Artifact Name at: **/ivy-module/publications/artifact/@name** is defined as **myorg-suitecreator** However **Grab** appears to be attempt to download: **SuiteCreator.jar**.

The artifact pattern in grapeConfig.xml is:

```
<artifact pattern="/data/ivy/repo/[organisation]/[module]/[branch]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
```

And so the file I'm trying to grab is actually: */data/ivy/repo/myorg/SuiteCreator/1.16.1/myorg-suitecreator-1.16.1.jar*

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this to work (or if Grab can download artifacts with different artifact name to the module name from Ivy?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to use Grab to achieve this. I found another limitation of Grab is that it doesn't allow the specification of the **branch** of the artifact you wish to retrieve. I realise that not having releases on a **master** branch or a single release branch may not be best practice, but we do have this requirement in our dev environment.

Instead I simply used an **Invoke Ant** build step within Jenkins to retrieve my Ivy artifact. We use ANT already in our dev process so this was not difficult.
[image: Invoke Ant Build Step]

The ANT build.xml script is located in the same git repository as the Groovy script I wish to run. The **retrieve-suite-creator** target is simply an [ivy-retrieve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.5.0-rc1/use/retrieve.html)

```
<target name="retrieve-suite-creator" depends="clean, install-ivy">
    <ivy:retrieve conf="suite-creator" type="jar" pattern="${build.dir}/[artifact].[ext]" log="${ivy.resolve.log}" settingsRef="${ivy.build.settings}"/>
</target>
```

Using my ivy.xml (again in the same repo as the groovy script):

```
<ivy-module version="1.0">
    <info organisation="myorg" module="MyAutomation" status="integration" branch="${ivy.branch}"/> 
    <configurations>
        <conf name="suite-creator" description="Configuration for Suite Creator"/>
    </configurations>
    <dependencies> 
        <dependency org="myorg" name="SuiteCreator" branch="mybranch" rev="1.16.1" conf="suite-creator->suite-creator" changing="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

I had to add the **suite-creator** ivy configuration to the SuiteCreator module's ivy.xml (in a separate SuiteCreator Git repo). I couldn't use the existing **jar** configuration as this also downloaded all the transitive dependencies which I didn't need.

```
<ivy-module version="1.0">
    <info organisation="myorg" module="SuiteCreator" status="integration" branch="${ivy.branch}"/>
    <configurations>
        <!-- Build configurations -->
        <conf name="build" description="Classes used in jar compilation"/>
        <conf name="jar" description="Distribution jar"/>
        <conf name="suite-creator" description="Just the myorg-suitecreator.jar"/>
    </configurations>

    <publications>
        <artifact name="myorg-suitecreator" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="jar,suite-creator"/>
    </publications>

    <dependencies>
    ...
    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Finally in my Jenkins job after the **Invoke Ant** build step, I then had an **Execute Groovy Script** build step, where I had to add the downloaded jar to my **Class path**.
[image: Execute Groovy Script build step]